# Query over form.helper for Django-crispy-forms

Tags: django, django-forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Django Crispy Forms together with Twitter-bootstrap and following this page: http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/tags.html#bootstrap-layout-objects
The tag `{% crispy example_form example_form.helper %}` is giving me some error.

In my case: it is `{% crispy gameserver gameserver.helper %}`.

It is giving me this weird error:

```
Failed lookup for key [gameserver] in u"[{}, {'csrf_token': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x10e417210>}, {'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x10e417290>, 'user': <django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0x10e40ad10>}, {}, {'LANGUAGES': (('ar', 'Arabic'), ('az', 'Azerbaijani'), ('bg', 'Bulgarian'), ('bn', 'Bengali'), ('bs', 'Bosnian'), ('ca', 'Catalan'), ('cs', 'Czech'), ('cy', 'Welsh'), ('da', 'Danish'), ('de', 'German'), ('el', 'Greek'), ('en', 'English'), ('en-gb', 'British English'), ('eo', 'Esperanto'), ('es', 'Spanish'), ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'), ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'), ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'), ('et', 'Estonian'), ('eu', 'Basque'), ('fa', 'Persian'), ('fi', 'Finnish'), ('fr', 'French'), ('fy-nl', 'Frisian'), ('ga', 'Irish'), ('gl', 'Galician'), ('he', 'Hebrew'), ('hi', 'Hindi'), ('hr', 'Croatian'), ('hu', 'Hungarian'), ('id', 'Indonesian'), ('is', 'Icelandic'), ('it', 'Italian'), ('ja', 'Japanese'), ('ka', 'Georgian'), ('kk', 'Kazakh'), ('km', 'Khmer'), ('kn', 'Kannada'), ('ko', 'Korean'), ('lt', 'Lithuanian'), ('lv', 'Latvian'), ('mk', 'Macedonian'), ('ml', 'Malayalam'), ('mn', 'Mongolian'), ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmal'), ('ne', 'Nepali'), ('nl', 'Dutch'), ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'), ('pa', 'Punjabi'), ('pl', 'Polish'), ('pt', 'Portuguese'), ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'), ('ro', 'Romanian'), ('ru', 'Russian'), ('sk', 'Slovak'), ('sl', 'Slovenian'), ('sq', 'Albanian'), ('sr', 'Serbian'), ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'), ('sv', 'Swedish'), ('sw', 'Swahili'), ('ta', 'Tamil'), ('te', 'Telugu'), ('th', 'Thai'), ('tr', 'Turkish'), ('tt', 'Tatar'), ('uk', 'Ukrainian'), ('ur', 'Urdu'), ('vi', 'Vietnamese'), ('zh-cn', 'Simplified Chinese'), ('zh-tw', 'Traditional Chinese')), 'LANGUAGE_BIDI': False, 'LANGUAGE_CODE': 'en-us'}, {'MEDIA_URL': ''}, {'STATIC_URL': '/static/'}, {'TIME_ZONE': 'CDT'}, {'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x10e412310>}, {'form': <polls.models.GSMemberForm object at 0x10e3f69d0>}]"
```

Need some guidance over it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call it with `{% crispy gameserver helper %}` if `gameserver` is the name of your form within the context and `helper` is the `FormHelper` instance. If you haven't created a separate `FormHelper` instance and you've created one attached to the form itself, you can do `{% crispy form form.helper_attribute %}`

If your form has a `FormHelper` attached to `helper` attribute (using `helper` as the name), then you don't have to pass a separate `helper`. Just do `{% crispy form %}`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this: `{% crispy gameserver gameserver.helper %}`

Type this: `{% crispy form %}`